# Why is VS 2013 code coverage different for same assembly in separate solutions

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to analyze code coverage for a solution in Visual Studio 2013, but there's an aspect to the numbers that I don't understand.  We have one solution that contains all the projects (both live and test).  We also have separate solutions that contain a subset of those same projects for deployment reasons.

For example:

Solution S references projects X, Y, and Z plus X.Tests, Y.Tests, and Z.Tests

Solution T references project X plus X.Tests.

Solution U references project X plus X.Tests.

When I run Code Coverage in VS 2013 for the different solutions S, T, and U, the blocks covered/not covered in project X are different in all three cases. I expected the same level of coverage for that project in all solutions as there is no difference.  Could someone point me to resource that explains this discrepancy?

Comment: Are they true unit tests (e.g. isolated), or integration tests? If they're integration tests, different data could cause different code paths to be hit. Additionally, is the code being compiled and tested against the exact same configuration in terms of things like optimizations being enabled?

Comment: True unit tests, they don't rely on any test data from outside the test assembly, not even flat-file config or anything like that.  Good question, code is compiled and tested against the same configuration in all cases.